# Can you Diagonalize an Augmented Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If I have an augmented matrix such that [5x4|5x1], is that matrix diagonizable? I'm not certain if it is considered square.

Comment: oops! I meant [5x4|5x1]

Comment: You can diagonalize it, but there's no good reason to do so. Diagonalization is not just something you can do, it's something that has a purpose and a meaning. Diagonalizing an augmented matrix has neither. Diagonalizing an augmented matrix, it's like frying a newspaper.

Comment: Understood now?

Comment: Yes, that was helpful, thank you for your input.